# Crontab not running python script, no errors no nothing

Tags: linux, bash, script, python, crontab

Already spent over 1h to make that easy thing and totally failed :/

Cant find why that python not working on crontab while it works perfect in commandline...

Script is (bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

touch before_zzz_text.txt # to check if cron works at all 
ls > "before_zzz_text.txt" # just to check if I'm in the correct directory

/root/anaconda3/bin/python -V > pv.txt # this is empty! or a white char

touch after_zzz_text.txt # this works new file every minute
```

This way I know it runs in cron (files .txt both created every minute - like cron runs every minute).

However pv.txt is empty ... so looks like bash script not working ?

In the end I want more complicated script to run in the bash script but I tried to dig why it's not working so to simplify it is now "/root/anaconda3/bin/python -V'

Comment: Is `/root/anaconda3/bin/python` the python script file? This is confusing, since `python` is the handler you want to run. Does it start with `#!/usr/bin/python` or similar? Does it and all its directory components have execute-all permissions? This is important, as the `crontab` environment is not the same as for your terminal. If the `.txt` files were deleted beforehand, what permissions and user / group names were they created with?

Comment: "/root/anaconda3/bin/python" is path for python interpreter. It was just "python" before but I though it cannot find the right env path or sth. Anyway with just "python -V > pv.txt" does not work either. Also there is no error messages , file pv.txt ic reated empty ... Should it be like that? "python -V should simply give python version and ">pv.txt" should store that message in that file, which comes empty in the end ...

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because `/root/anaconda3/bin/` is an unlikely location for the interpreter. An empty log file will be produced if an error prevents the interpreter from running. Add `2>&1` to the end of the `python` call to see any errors.

Comment: No problem got the fix finally! Seems the missing MTA on ubuntu server was messing around. After adding "2>&1" to the python line it works!!!!

Comment: I didn't realise that the version was written to `stderr`: like you, I had assumed it would be on `stdout`, but I've just confirmed this on my own system. Glad you're in business. I think I'll submit an answer, for the benefit of other users of the site.

Comment: I'm still not sure it is, but somehow it works after adding the "2>&1" part. This is more like solution when MTA is not installed I think.

Comment: You shouldn't place an answer inside a question. If you think the existing answer is not enough then add your own answer. Use [this link](https://superuser.com/revisions/1266128/2) if you want to copy-paste your "answer" to an actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of discussion (see the comments above), it seems that the basic problem is that `python` writes its version text to `stderr`, not the expected `stdout`, where nothing is written, hence the empty file.

In general, when diagnosing `crontab` problems, it is a good idea to log errors as well as output, to the same or a different file. By adding `2>&1` to the end of the `python` invocation line, the version text appeared in `pv.txt`:

```
/root/anaconda3/bin/python -V > pv.txt 2>&1
```